# Redirecting to .aspx in a different domain

Tags: asp.net, redirect, refer

Okay, I'm dealing with a problem hear.
I'm building landing pages for my company.
The main website works with a .aspx form to retrieve car data (from for example licenseplates).

Now we've set up some new relevant domain names to use for some of the landing pages.
The problem now is, that when on those pages I type in licenseplate and click search, it fails doing so.
Since it tries to find the .aspx form on the landing page domain url.

For example:

Main site: www.mysite.com/category.aspx?k=80zbfk (refered to when the licenseplate is typed in.)
Landing page: www.mysite2.com/category.aspx?k=80zbfk (were it refers to on the landing page)

No the second one should refer to the first one. But I can't seem to find a way to do so.
I don't have acces to the .aspx files since they're in control of a external company.
Is there any way to fix this? To refer the landing page to the .aspx from the main site?
Or do I have to contact the webcompany to ask for the files so I can copy them to the other domain?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be using absolute links rather than relative.

An absolute link includes the host *and* path of the target url, whereas a relative one contains only the path and lets the browser infer the host (via the url being visited).

For example, if you were editing the HTML of a page here on Stack Overflow, the absolute link to this question would look something like this,

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379795/redirecting-to-aspx-in-a-different-domain
```

While the relative one would look like this,

```
/questions/26379795/redirecting-to-aspx-in-a-different-domain
```

In the case of the latter one, the browser would be left to assume based on context that you wanted to go to that path on `http://stackoverflow.com/`. There's a bit more to it, and variations on that syntax exist. But that's the gist of it.

So, getting back to your question, yes. You will probably have to update the ASPX pages. Relative links are best practice in most cases, which explains why they were used in your code, but you've got an exception. It's probably going to be easiest to just go through and change whatever links you need, to point to the main domain. But for what it's worth, that should be a relatively easy fix, once you get the files.

Alternatively, you could set up a rewrite rule or redirection policy on your landing page servers to automatically 301 redirect any requests that contain search information off to the main server, but that's definitely a workaround approach, and there will be a performance hit in doing so. The one and only advantage that I can imagine to doing that is that you wouldn't need to get the pages from the third party, but it sounds like that wouldn't be a bad idea to do anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I copied the master .js file to the new domain and changed the relative urls from the .aspx to absolute links. 
It works now.